# Kendo UI - Pop-Up / Window - JS will not execute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo UI window dialog / pop-up to simulate a fullscreen work mode within the application I am designing. However, whenever my pop-up window is open, all of my javascript function stop working. Is there a way to re-render inline js when this window is opened? Is there a way to call an external JS file when this window is opened?

P.S. My window is getting it's content by copying html from the current screen into a div when a button is clicked.

Here is a sample of my code, you can see when I click the "PopOut" button, it clones content of the current module to the kendow-window:

When  you click the expand icon in the top right corner, it calls the PopOut function, which clones the current module(the section below with content)  into a kendo window that fills the entire browser window, giving the effect of a fullscreen mode.

[image]

```
function kendoWindow2() {
    $("#windowButtonPopOut").click();
}
$(document).ready(function () {
var window = $("#windowPopOut"),
    undo = $("#windowButtonPopOut")
            .bind("click", function () {
                var h = $(document).height();
                var w = $(document).width();
                $("div.k-window").css("width", w);
                $("div.k-window").css("height", h);
                console.log(h, w);
                window.data("kendoWindow").open().center();
                undo.hide();
                $(".k-window .title").remove();
                $(".k-window .k-window-titlebar").remove();
                $(".k-window").css("padding-top","0px");

            });
var onClose = function () {
    undo.show();
    $("#content .module").css("visibility", "visible");

}
if (!window.data("kendoWindow")) {


    window.kendoWindow({
        title: "",
        actions: [
            "Close"
        ],
        close: onClose
    });
}
```

});

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: please add a minimal example of what you're trying to do for the unfortunate few who aren't clairvoyant

Comment: Added the k-window JS snippet. Maybe that will help?